# CKEditor set data, clicking on text area after clearing text set?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor and when i click on a drop down it populates the editor with the set data function.

But when the user clicks on the area it clears all the text.

If the user clicks on the area first, writes one letter and then changed the drop down to populate the editor it is fine.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { id = "email-body", placeholder = "Start typing your message...", autocomplete = "off" })

CKEDITOR.instances["email-body"].setData(msg.success)
```

any assistance on how to stop the onclick clear placeholder in the ckeditor?

Comment: Is there a link we could check out? Have you tried removing the placeholder? It could be at fault here possibly. Is this an inline or a normal editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this  will work for you.

```
CKEDITOR.instances["email-body"].updateElement();
CKEDITOR.instances["email-body"].setData('');
```

Comment: I have tired this but no difference, it places the set data in more as a placeholder then the actual text

Comment: CKEDITOR.instances.deals_description.setData("");

Comment: nope still when click on text area after it clears, it sets data as a place holder

Comment: Hey dude i have already used that in my application and it's work fine    may be you have written some another function on the page and text area.

Comment: Yes took the placeholder otu and it works, but with a placeholder it does not.